# The page got through Ajax cannot use the input type = "file" label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I get form page through Ajax. 
The following is a form of code:

```
enter code here
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:0px;">
        <label for="file">注：选择头像文件尽量小于2M</label>
        <input id="headPortraitFile" type="file" name="portrait"> 
    </div>
    <button id="headPortraitSubmit" type="button" class="btn-sm btn-primary">上传头像</button>
</form>
```

But the form of the input type = "file" in the browser cannot selected file directly, not to mention the submitted documents. I do not know what reason be? This two days have not been solved, for a great god!!!!!!

here is the Ajax code:
1.I get the form page by this:

```
$(Document).on("click", '#headPortrait', function() {
    $.get("/headPortrait", function(data) {
        $(".bodyPart").children().remove();
        $(".bodyPart").html(data);
    })
})
```

2.and then I post the form by this:

```
$(Document).on("click", '#headPortraitSubmit', function() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("portrait", $('#headPortraitFile').get(0).files[0])
    $.ajax({ 
        url : "/headPortraitSubmit", 
        type : 'POST', 
        data : formData, 
        processData : false, 
        contentType : false,
        beforeSend:function(){
            console.log("正在进行，请稍候");
        },
        success : function(data) { 
            if (data = "success") {
                $(".bodyPart").children().remove();
                $(".bodyPart").load('/coding');
            }
        }, 
    });
})
```

Comment: your ajax code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: You can transfer a file through AJAX with XHR2, but it's not supported by old borwsers (mainly IE < 10, so surprising). However, you can use an IFRAME. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2320097/6424295)

Comment: @Emilio Venegas   Thankyou at first !  I Have been refer to the answer before asking this question . I think they are different~

Comment: The question is I can't input file at the form page. But I think the Ajax code is not the reason.

Comment: Why do you set contentType to false?  Do you not want "multipart/form-data"?

Comment: @John Hascall The result is the same as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` attribute value should match `id` of `<input type="file">` if expected result is for `change` event to be called for `<input type="file">` element when `<label>` element is clicked. Substitute  `"submit"` for `"button"` at `type` attribute of `<button>`.

`Document` is a function, not `html` `document`. Substitute `document` for `Document` at parameter passed to `jQuery()` : `$()`.

`if` condition within `success` should use `==` or `===` to compare value of `data` to `"success"`, instead of assigning `"success"` to `data` identifier.

```
$(document).on(/* event, selector, eventHandler */)
```

```js
$(document).on("click", '#headPortraitSubmit', function() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("portrait", $('#headPortraitFile').get(0).files[0]);
    console.log(formData.get("portrait"));
    /*
    $.ajax({ 
        url : "/headPortraitSubmit", 
        type : 'POST', 
        data : formData, 
        processData : false, 
        contentType : false,
        beforeSend:function(){
            console.log("正在进行，请稍候");
        },
        success : function(data) { 
            if (data === "success") {
                $(".bodyPart").children().remove();
                $(".bodyPart").load('/coding');
            }
        }, 
    });
    */
});

document.querySelector("form")
.onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

document.querySelector("input[id=headPortraitFile]")
.onchange = function(event) {
  console.log(this.files[0])
}
```

```css
input[type=file] {
  display: none;
}

[for=headPortraitFile]:before {
  content: 'Label for #headPortraitFile ';
}

#headPortraitSubmit:before {
  content: 'Sumbit form .form-horizontal ';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:0px;">
    <label for="headPortraitFile">注：选择头像文件尽量小于2M</label>
    <input id="headPortraitFile" type="file" name="portrait">
  </div>
  <button id="headPortraitSubmit" type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-primary">上传头像</button>
</form>
```